# mysql query will only return results if i hard code the text in the database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MYSQL database with a query. The query only works if I manually type in the data with MYSQL Admin or with the following statement $sn="x-xxx"; It will not return results if i pass $sn to the database from a form even though the $sn get inserted into the database just fine.  I can look at the database and see that it's there.  Not sure if why the query would only pull down the records I manually imputed.

Comment: Sounds like there's an error in your code that needs to be corrected.  Good luck!

Comment: You need to post the relevant code, and likely someone here will spot the error immediately. For example, incorrectly quoting the string variable `$sn` in the query.

Comment: If you are sure the rows are there, then check for spurious characters (newline? tab?) stored in the column. `SELECT col, CHAR_LENGTH(col), HEX(col) FROM mytable WHERE col LIKE '%x-xxx%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys.  I found that by passing the variable from page to page that a space was being added to the variable. I used:
$sn=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $sn); and var_dump($sn); to strip the space and to check what was being posed.  Wow  5 full days trying to find this. Thanks to everybody who answered.